# Request авторизация

Tags: python, requests, auth

Мне нужно сделать авторизацию на сайт . Если я введу какой-либо верный или неверный пароль, то программа вернет результат <response 200>. Если я вывожу *resp.text* получаю html страницы входа(lk.vertical.ru/auth)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://lk.vertical.ru/auth/'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0'
}
catalog = 'https://lk.vertical.ru/catalog/instrument/'
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
res = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
data = {
    'sessid': soup.find('input', {"name": "sessid"}).get("value"),
    'LOGIN': 'xxxxxxx',
    'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxx',
    'remember': [
        "0",
        "1"
    ]
}
response = s.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
resp = s.get(catalog, data=data, headers=headers)
print(resp.text)
```

Comment: Так, а вопрос/проблема собственно в чём заключается?

Comment: мне нужно зайти через сессию на страницу каталога, но когда пытаюсь это сделать, ответом приходит страница авторизации

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
url = 'https://lk.vertical.ru/auth/'
session = requests.Session()
res = session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
sessid = soup.find(attrs={'name': 'sessid'})['value']

files = [
    ('sessid', (None, sessid)),
    ('LOGIN', (None, 'qwweert')),
    ('PASSWORD', (None, '1234567')),
    ('remember', (None, '0')),
    ('remember', (None, '1')),
]

response = session.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)
print(response.json())

# {'success': False, 'errorFields': {'LOGIN': 'Неверный логин или пароль.'}}
```

Comment: ооо, спасибо большое!
могли бы объяснить почему данные нужно передавать через files?

Comment: Content-Type: multipart/form-data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python